# How to get view of map based on place name wihout knowing latitude and longitude?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-maps

I want to display small map in web page.I have only place name with me.I don't have latitude and longitude of place.
suppose my place is
"`AH Wadia Marg, Friends Colony, Hallow Pul, Kurla, Mumbai, Maharashtra 400070`"

is there any way to display?

Comment: why not geolocate the place?

Comment: The site doesn't work this way (providing code on demand). You must do your research, and create some code yourself. If at this time you still have problems, then other users here can help you. See [ask].

Comment: You need a service for that. Google offers such a service. You could also google for the google service (okay not so funny joke maybe :) ).

Comment: when i searched all codes are based on latitude and longitude

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $lat; ?>, <?php echo $long; ?>);
    var addressMarker = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $lat; ?>, <?php echo $long; ?>);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 16,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        myOptions);

 marker = new google.maps.Marker({ map:map, position: addressMarker });
  }

</script>`

Comment: Use the [google maps geocoding service](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=AH%20Wadia%20Marg,%20Friends%20Colony,%20Hallow%20Pul,%20Kurla,%20Mumbai,%20Maharashtra%20400070&geocode=1)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you want, but the Google Maps API allows you to display a location based solely on the name.

If you want a static image:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/

If you want an interactive map: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide

Answer (score 0):

You need to use google geo code, For that first you need to collect whole address and make comma separated string and then need to pass to geo code, Please take a look to below code.

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

var address = $("#address").val() + ' ' + $("#city").val() + ' ' + $("#state").val() + ' ' + $("#zipcode").val();

    if (geocoder) {                                                                                    

geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function (results, status) {
                                                                                                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                                                                                            $('#LoadMap').locationpicker({
                                                                                                location: {latitude: results[0].geometry.location.k, longitude: results[0].geometry.location.D},
                                                                                                radius: 300,
                                                                                                inputBinding: {
                                                                                                    locationNameInput: $('#AddressAutoComplete')
                                                                                                },
                                                                                                enableAutocomplete: true,
                                                                                                onchanged: function (currentLocation, radius, isMarkerDropped) {
                                                                                                    $('#address_loc0').val(currentLocation.latitude + ',' + currentLocation.longitude);                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                }    
                                                                                            });
                                                                                        }                                                                                         
                                                                                    });
}
```